# Do I need Pagination, Lazy Loading or none in my React-Native app?

Tags: react-native, pagination, google-cloud-firestore, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I am implementing an app in React-Native where I am fetching "restaurants" as documents from Cloud-Firestore and I am also using onSnapshot() listener. When the app is ready for launch, there will probably be around max 3000 restaurants. I have a few questions to ask around this matter.

**-Do I need to implement Pagination/Lazy Loading for a better UX and less cost OR 3000 is not a big number so it won't affect the performance that much?!**

**-If I do need to implement one of them, which one should I implement?**

**-If I dont need, then is there a way to compress the JSON data when fetching in React-Native so it saves space? And then decompress when requested by the user.**

**Can user search for a restaurant while lazy loading is implemented?**

**EDIT**:
I managed to implement lazy-loading and its working perfectly, however, using `snapshot()` listener will make lazy-loading pointless but I must use it because I need to fetch on real-time new "restaurants" or "orders. So, what else can I use instead of `snapshot()`? Or maybe is there a way to still use `snapshot()` but with a small change to the code?

Second question: after the above problem is solved, am I able to implement the search for a restaurant? It seems quite tricky knowing that I am using lazy-loading.

```
  componentDidMount() {
        try {
            // Cloud Firestore: Initial Query
            this.retrieveData();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    retrieveData = () => {
        try {
            this.setState({
                loading: true
            })

            var initialQuery = firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants')
                .orderBy('res_id')
                .limit(this.state.limit)

            //let documentSnapshots = await initialQuery.get();

            initialQuery.onSnapshot((documentSnapshots => {
                var All = documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());


                var lastVisible = All[All.length - 1].res_id;
                this.setState({
                    All: All,
                    lastVisible: lastVisible,
                    loading: false,
                });
            }));


        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    retrieveMore = async () => {
        try {
            // Set State: Refreshing
            this.setState({
                refreshing: true,
            });

            // Cloud Firestore: Query (Additional Query)
            var additionalQuery = await firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants')

                .orderBy('res_id')
                .startAfter(this.state.lastVisible)
                .limit(this.state.limit)
            // Cloud Firestore: Query Snapshot
            var documentSnapshots = await additionalQuery.get();
            // Cloud Firestore: Document Data
            var All = documentSnapshots.docs.map(document => document.data());
            // Cloud Firestore: Last Visible Document (Document ID To Start From For Proceeding Queries)
            var lastVisible = All[All.length - 1].res_id;
            // Set State
            this.setState({
                All: [...this.state.All, ...All],
                lastVisible: lastVisible,
                refreshing: false,
            });
            console.log('Retrieving additional Data', this.state.All);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };


    // Render Header
    renderHeader = () => {
        try {
            return (
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Items</Text>
            )
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    // Render Footer
    renderFooter = () => {
        try {
            // Check If Loading
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return (
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                )
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    // Data
                    data={this.state.All}
                    // Render Items
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                            <Text>(ID: {item.res_id}) {item.rest_name} {item.rest_location}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                    // Item Key
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                    // Header (Title)
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                    // Footer (Activity Indicator)
                    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
                    // On End Reached (Takes a function)
                    onEndReached={this.retrieveMore}
                    // How Close To The End Of List Until Next Data Request Is Made
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                    // Refreshing (Set To True When End Reached)
                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination and Lazy Loading are kind of the same thing in this case. You will be either switching pages or infinitely scrolling while fetching new data until there is no more data to fetch. In either case, you need it. Look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

As pagination is merely a way you query your data, it has no effect on how you can use this data in other ways, meaning sure you can search for a restaurant given your database design and security rules are set up right

Not sure if you should be using onSnapshot listener though, as it will return you entire collection every time something changes, which denies the whole point of using pagination

**EDIT:**

About real time updates: it depends on what do you want to fetch in real time. Is it only those restaurants you have loaded or all of them? Imagine you had 1.000.000 restaurants in your db, you sure wouldn't want to query for them all for real time updates. Refreshing only those that are currently loaded is pretty expensive operation in firestore as it requires canceling and creating new subscriptions every time your visible restaurants change (e.g. as you scroll through the page). So both variants are not an option

You should reconsider your app design - e.g. do you really need to live track orders of every restaurant registered? Maybe you only want those where you are an employee, or only those near you? Maybe you should restructure your database to keep orders separately from restaurants, that way you can listen for orders while still lazy loading restaurants?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Please check my question I have edited and added my code where I managed to implement lazy-loading but as you said onsnapshot() will be pointless in this case. What else can I do instead because I really need to fetch data on real-time?

Comment: thanks again! Here is what I need to do: I currently am displaying restaurants in one of the 'react-native-snap-carousel' that I have in front page, I have 2 in total. The other carousel is displaying the latest discounts, so I need to listen for changes in the discounts collection as there will be updates constantly. And then I need to display the latest discount as the first item of the carousel.